# Error while convering tensor flow decision tree model into TFlite model

Tags: python, firebase, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert the RandomForest model from tensor_flow_decision_tree into a TFlite model.It keeps giving me the following error.What do i do?

> ConverterError: :0: error:
> loc(fused["SimpleMLCreateModelResource:",
> "SimpleMLCreateModelResource"]): 'tf.SimpleMLCreateModelResource' op
> is neither a custom op nor a flex op :0: note:
> loc(fused["SimpleMLCreateModelResource:",
> "SimpleMLCreateModelResource"]): Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_CUSTOM_OPS
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:749:0:
> error: 'tf.SimpleMLInferenceOpWithHandle' op is neither a custom op
> nor a flex op :0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:",
> "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:749:0:
> note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_CUSTOM_OPS :0: error: failed
> while converting: 'main':  Some ops in the model are custom ops, See
> instructions to implement custom ops:
> https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom  Custom ops:
> SimpleMLCreateModelResource, SimpleMLInferenceOpWithHandle Details:
> tf.SimpleMLCreateModelResource() -> (tensor<!tf_type.resource>) :
> {container = "", device = "", shared_name =
> "simple_ml_model_243450c3-97d3-43ae-bd29-ea9628cd031d"}
> tf.SimpleMLInferenceOpWithHandle(tensor<?x12xf32>, tensor<0x0xf32>,
> tensor<0x0xi32>, tensor<0xi32>, tensor<1xi64>, tensor<1xi64>,
> tensor<!tf_type.resource>) -> (tensor<?x2xf32>,
> tensor<2x!tf_type.string>) : {dense_output_dim = 2 : i64, device = ""}

[image: Image of Errors]

I tried checking the guide but could not find anyting helpful

Comment: Are you sure decision tree models are eligible to be converted to tflite? Ask that at TensorFlow forum and tag Richard Stotz or Gustavo martins.

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of Tensorflow Decision Forests.

Decision Forests are not yet compatible with TFLite, so the conversion is unfortunately not possible. Feel free to tell the team about your uses case on the [TF-DF Github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests) to help prioritize this feature.